# Not making space?

Tags: math-mode, errors

The system of linear equations

```
\[6x_1 + 4x_2 = 9 \\
x_1 + 5x_2 = 0
\]
```

can be also depicted as

```
\[ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
6 & 4 & 9 \\
1 & 5 & 0 \end{array} \right).
\]
```

When it is entered in latex, the `9` is displayed next to the `x_1` and I need that fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\\` can not be used to break a paragraph in math mode...

Probably you wanted something like

[image]

or

[image]

Code (for both of them)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
6x_1 + 4x_2 = 9\\
x_1 + 5x_2 = 0
\end{gather*}

\begin{align*}
6x_1 + 4x_2 & = 9\\
x_1 + 5x_2 & = 0
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably expecting:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}    

The system of linear equations

\[
\begin{array}{r}
6x_1 + 4x_2 = 9 \\
x_1 + 5x_2 = 0
\end{array}
\]
can be also depicted as 
\[ 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 6 & 4 & 9 \\ 
1 & 5 & 0 \end{array} 
\right). 
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The meaning of double backslash depends on the place where it is used. In pure equations it has no result, but in an `array` environment it acts as the end of a row of a matrix. We can think that rows are here one column long, if we adjust them to the right.

Comment: While helpful, your answer doesn't explain what's wrong with the OP's code. Perhaps you should add some information.

Comment: @Jubobs Enlarged. I hope that my poor English is understandable.